# Traceback Error : raise self.model.DoesNotExist(__fake__.StartUp.DoeNotExist: StartUp matching query does not exist

Tags: python, django, django-models

This is my models.py file

```
from django.db import models

from django.urls import reverse
```

```
    class Tag(models.Model):

        name = models.CharField(max_length=31, unique=True)

        slug = models.SlugField(max_length=31, unique=True, help_text = 'A label for URL config')
    
         class Meta:
            ordering = ['name']
    
            def __str__(self):
            return self.name.title()
    
     def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('organizer_tag_detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
        
     def get_update_url(self):
        return reverse('organizer_tag_update', kwargs={'slug' : self.slug})
     def get_delete_url(self):
        return reverse('organizer_tag_delete', kwargs={'slug':self.slug}) 
    
    class StartUp(models.Model):

        name = models.CharField(max_length=31, db_index=True)
        slug = models.SlugField(max_length=31,unique=True, help_text='A label for URL config')
        description = models.TextField()
        founded_date = models.DateField()
        contact = models.EmailField('date founded')
        website = models.URLField()
        tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True)
    
       class Meta:
          ordering = ['name']
          get_latest_by = 'founded_date'
    
         def __str__(self):
           return self.name
    
     def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('organizer_startup_detail', kwargs={'slug':self.slug })
    
     def get_update_url(self):
        return reverse('organizer_startup_update', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
    
     def get_delete_url(self):
        return reverse('organizer_startup_delete', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

    class NewsLink(models.Model):

      title = models.CharField(max_length=63)
      slug = models.SlugField(max_length=63)
      pub_date = models.DateField('date published')
      link = models.URLField(max_length=255)
      startup = models.ForeignKey(StartUp, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
      class Meta:
         verbose_name ='news article'
         ordering = ['-pub_date']
         get_latest_by = 'pub_date'
         unique_together = ('slug', 'startup')
    
    
          def __str__(self):
             return "{} : {}" .format(
             self.startup, self.title
           )

      def get_absolute_url(self):
           return self.startup.get_absolute_url()
    
    def get_update_url(self):
        return reverse('organizer_newslink_update', kwargs={'pk':self.pk})
    
    def get_delete_url(self):
        return reverse('organizer_newslink_delete', kwargs={'pk':self.pk})    



............................................................................................
This is migration file for startup 
from django.db import migrations
from datetime import date


    STARTUPS = [

  {
    "name" : "Arachnobots",
    "slug": "arachnobots",
    "contact": "contact@arachnobots.com",
    "description":
        "Remote-controlled-internet-enabled"
        "Spider Robots",
    "founded_date": date(2014, 10, 31),
    "tags" : ["mobile", "augmented-reality"],
    "website" :
            "http://frightenyourroommate.com/"

  },
  {
      "name" : "Boundless-Software",
      "slug" : "boundless-software",
      "contact" : "hello@boundless.com",
      "description" : "The Sky was the limit",
      "founded_date" :  date(2013, 5, 15),
      "tags" : ["big-data"],
      "website" : "http://boundless.com"
  },
  {
      "name" : "Game Congress",
      "slug" : "game-congress",
      "contact" : "vote@gamecongress.com",
      "description" : "By gamers for gamers of gamers",
      "founded_date" : date(2012, 7, 4),
      "tag" : ["video-games"],
      "website" : "http://gamecongress.com/",
  },
  {
      "name" : "JamBon Software",
      "slug" : "jambon-software",
      "contact" : "django@jambonsw.com",
      "description": "JamBon Software is a consulting "
            "company that specializes in web and "
            "mobile products. They can carry out "
            "Full end to end development of new "
            "products, or review and advise on existing "
            "products. They also offer hands on training in "
            "Django.",
        "founded_date" : date(2013, 1, 18),
        "tags" : ["django"],
        "website" : "http://jambonsw.com"
            
  },
  {
      "name" : "Lightning Rod Challenge",
      "slug" : "lightning-rod-challenge",
      "contact" : "hello@lightningrode.com",
      "description" :
          "Channel the storm "
          "Trouble shoot the cloud.",
       "founded_date" : date(2014,1,1),
       "tags" : ["ipython", "jupyter", "big-data"],
       "website" : "http://lightningrode.com",
  },
  {
      "name" : "Monkey Software",
      "slug" : "monkey-software",
      "contact" : "shakespear@monkeysw.com",
      "description" :
          "1000 code monkey making software.",
      "founded_date" : date(2014, 12, 10),
      "tags" : ["video-games"],
      "website" : "http://monkeysw.com/",
  },
  {
      "name": "Simple Robots",
      "slug" : "simple-robots",
      "contact" : "yoshimi@simplerobots.com",
      "description" :
            "Your resource to understanding "
            "computer, robots, and technology.",
      "founded_date" : date(2010, 1, 2),
      "tags" : ["python", "augmented-reality"],
      "website" : "http://simplerobots.com/",
  },
  {
      "name" : "Thingles",
      "slug" : "thingles",
      "contact" : "help@lightningrod.com",
      "description" :
          "A market place for arduino, "
          "raspberry pi, and other "
          "homemade stuff.",
     "founded_date" : date(2015, 4, 7),
     "tags" : ["python"],
     "website" :"http://buythingles.com/",
  },
]

    class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    
    def add_startup_data(apps, scheme_editor):
       StartUp = apps.get_model('organizer', 'StartUp')
       Tag = apps.get_model('organizer', 'Tag')
       
       for startup in STARTUPS:
           startup_object = StartUp.objects.create(
               name = startup['name'],
               slug = startup['slug'],
               contact = startup['contact'],
               description = startup['description'],
               founded_date = startup['founded_date'],
               website = startup['website'])
           for tag_slug in startup['tags']:
                startup_object.tags.add(
                Tag.objects.get(slug=tag_slug)
                )
                
    
    def remove_startup_data(app, scheme_editor):
        StartUp = apps.get_model('organizer', 'StartUp')
        for startup in STARTUPS:
            startup_object = StartUp.objects.get(slug=startup['slug'])
            startup_object.delete()
        

    dependencies = [
        ('organizer', '0003_tag_data'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(add_startup_data, remove_startup_data)
    ]

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

This is my newslink migration file 

from django.db import migrations, models
from datetime import date

    NEWSLINKS = [

    {
        "title" :"Redundant Homepage Link",
        "link": "http://jambonsw.com",
        "pub_date" : date(2013,1, 18),
        "startup" : "jambon-software",
        
},
    {
        "title": "Monkey(Wikipedia)",
        "link": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey",
         "pub_date" : date(2012, 7, 22),
         "startup" : "monkey-software",
    },
    {
        "title" : "William Shakespeare",
        "link" : "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Shakespeare",
        "pub_date" : date(2014, 4, 26),
        "startup" : "monkey-software",
    },
]

    class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    def add_newslink_data(apps, schema_editor):
        NewsLink = apps.get_model('organizer', 'NewsLink')
        StartUp  = apps.get_model('organizer', 'StartUp')
        for newslink_dict in NEWSLINKS:
            newslink = NewsLink.objects.create(
                title = newslink_dict['title'],
                link = newslink_dict['link'],
                pub_date = newslink_dict['pub_date'],
                startup = StartUp.objects.get( 
                slug = newslink_dict['startup']))

    
    def remove_newslink_data(apps, schema_editor):
        NewsLink = apps.get_model('organizer', 'NewsLink')
        StartUp = apps.get_model('organizer', 'StartUp')
        
        for newslink_dict in NEWSLINK:
            newslink = NewsLink.objects.get(
                title = newslink_dict['title'],
                link = newslink_dict['link'],
                pub_date = newslink_dict['pub_date'],
                startup  = StartUp.objects.get(
                    slug = newslink_dict['startup']))
            newslink.delete()

    dependencies = [
        ('organizer', '0004_startup_data'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(add_newslink_data, remove_newslink_data)
    ]
```

---

This is traceback I get when I type command python manage.py migrate.

Applying organizer.0005_newslink_data...Traceback (most recent call last): File "E:\Django Unleashed\suorganizer\manage.py", line 22, in

```
main()
```

File "E:\Django Unleashed\suorganizer\manage.py", line 18, in main execute_from_command_line(sys.argv) File "E:\Django Unleashed\django-unleashed\lib\site- packages\django\core\management_init_.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()

File "E:\Django Unleashed\django-unleashed\lib\site- packages\django\core\management_init_.py", line 440, in execute self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv) File "E:\Django Unleashed\django-unleashed\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 402, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)

File "E:\Django Unleashed\django-unleashed\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 448, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)

File"E:\Django Unleashed\django-unleashed\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 96, in wrapped
res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "E:\Django Unleashed\django-unleashed\lib\site- packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 349, in handle
post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(

File "E:\Django Unleashed\django-unleashed\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 135, in migrate
state = self._migrate_all_forwards(

File "E:\Django Unleashed\django-unleashed\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 167, in _migrate_all_forwards
state = self.apply_migration(
File "E:\Django Unleashed\django-unleashed\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 252, in apply_migration

```
state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
```

File "E:\Django Unleashed\django-unleashed\lib\site- packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 130, in apply
operation.database_forwards(

File "E:\Django Unleashed\django-unleashed\lib\site- packages\django\db\migrations\operations\special.py", line 193, in database_forwards
self.code(from_state.apps, schema_editor)

File "E:\Django Unleashed\suorganizer\organizer\migrations\0005_newslink_data.py", line 37, in add_newslink_data
startup = StartUp.objects.get(
File "E:\Django Unleashed\django-unleashed\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "E:\Django Unleashed\django-unleashed\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 650, in get
raise self.model.DoesNotExist(

```
__fake__.StartUp.DoesNotExist: StartUp matching query does not exist.
```